# Using SVN from Eclipse and the terminal prompt

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn

I run ubuntu, and thus of cause I like the terminal prompt. I run most svn commands from the prompt. But I have a problem...
I checkout my code using the svn in a terminal:

```
svn co <svn-url> <local dir>
```

nice...

Now I go to eclipse and do the development...
I have subeclipse and lets say that I do a commit from the svn/eclipse gui.
Now if I go back to svn in a terminal and do:

```
svn commit
```

I get this:

> svn: This client is too old to work with working copy '/home/marhin/dev/trunk'.  You need
>   to get a newer Subversion client, or to downgrade this working copy.
>   See http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change
>   for details.

I have checked the link and as far as I can see i does  not help me...
My svn version is:

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.5.4 (r33841)
compiled Feb 23 2009, 20:42:53
```

my Subversion Client adapter version is: 1.6.0.2

Thanks

Comment: I have seen the same weird effect, but on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[change-svn-wc-format.py](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/tools/client-side/change-svn-wc-format.py)**  which can reform your workingcopy version to an older one. this is especially nice, if you are using eclipse, as they need some time to get to the current version. If you are used to command line jjust start this script after your last svn command and switch back to eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you answered your question. The Subversion Client you have is newer than the version you have on the command line.

You checked out the repository with an older version, Eclipse updated the files with the new version, and then your command line client starts screaming.

The easiest solution in your case would be updating your svn command line client.

Comment: are you sure that the version numbers are comparable ?
I'll give it a shot

Comment: If you are talking about svnClientAdaptor from Subclipse, I believe its version is directly related to the svn command line version.

Comment: Version numbers are comparable.  I had the same problem and it is really just a matter to ensure that the version numbers of both components are the same

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same problem since I often switch between SVN clients.  You need to ensure that your Eclipse SVN client is compatible with your command line client.  (Either upgrade your command line client or downgrade your eclipse client.)  If you do that, what you're doing will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

When Subversion changes the working copy version in a release (such as 1.5.x -> 1.6.x), any 1.5.x working copy is **silently** upgraded to the 1.6.x format as soon as it is **touched** by a 1.6.x client. This is pretty clearly stated in the release notes of 1.6.x.

The standard way of dealing with this is to **upgrade all your clients at the same time**.